# Http POST Accents encoding

Tags: python, http, urlencode

I have an encoding problem :
When I type the caracter 'é' in an input in a web browser, it is posted as %E9, and it works fine.
on the other hand, when I try to post a request using Python and requests library, it is sent as %C3%A9.

How could I solve the problem ?

Here is the code that does not work

```
requests.post("http://localhost", message = {"text":'é'})
```

Thanks

Comment: That is the wide char. Not sure how to change it just yet, hold on. (see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%C3%A9` is url-encoded version of utf-8 encoded string:

```
>>> u'é'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> urllib.quote(u'é'.encode('utf-8'))
'%C3%A9'
```

Explicitly encode the string with `latin-1` encoding (or similar):

```
>>> u'é'.encode('latin1')
'\xe9'
>>> urllib.quote(u'é'.encode('latin-1'))
'%E9'
```

---

```
requests.post("http://localhost", message={"text": u'é'.encode('latin-1')})
```

Comment: Cool. I've never used python, so it was taking me a bit to sift through it. I knew it was unicode, but couldn't figure out what to do to convert for the person asking. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! Just for the record, the last line is just requests.post("http://localhost", {"text": u'é'.encode('latin-1')}), without the keyword message