# How to use special characters (accents) on post requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests, character-encoding

I'm new here.

I found this forum through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965362/http-post-accents-encoding), and basically OP is having the same problem as I am, but the answer did not work for me.

What I want is to send a post request that sends a whatsapp message through an API, but if I try to use accents on the letters the message that is sent is completely broken ([see the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpNRn.png)) the weird diamond with a question mark was supposed to be an "é" character.

So, my question is: how can I make the "é" be sent through the whatsapp? Am I messing up with encoding or something?

Here's the code of what I'm trying to do:

```
def send_message():
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'x-maytapi-key': API_TOKEN,
    }
    url = INSTANCE_URL + "/" + PRODUCT_ID + "/" + PHONE_ID + "/sendMessage"
    data = '{ "message": "Essa mensagem \xe9 um teste, por favor desconsidere", "to_number": "+55XXXXXXXXXXX", "type": "text" }'
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The code above sends the message, but it arrives as seen on that picture (as the weird diamond)

Now here's what I've tried after seeing the forum post mentioned in the beginning:

```
def send_message():
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-maytapi-key': API_TOKEN,
    }
    url = INSTANCE_URL + "/" + PRODUCT_ID + "/" + PHONE_ID + "/sendMessage"
    data = '{ "message": "Essa mensagem \xe9 um teste, por favor desconsidere", "to_number": "+55XXXXXXXXX", "type": "text" }'.encode('latin-1')

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.text)
```

Result is, unfortunately, the same.

Comment: If you use the `data` parameter, you should json encode it first. `response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))`. Serializing python's basic types looks a lot like json so it works sometimes but sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `json=` parameter instead of `data=` when you do your request. Also, first try to remove the `Content-Type` header:

```py
def send_message():
    headers = {
        # "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "x-maytapi-key": API_TOKEN,
    }
    url = INSTANCE_URL + "/" + PRODUCT_ID + "/" + PHONE_ID + "/sendMessage"
    data = {
        "message": "Essa mensagem é um teste, por favor desconsidere",
        "to_number": "+55XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "type": "text",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Comment: Why remove the content type?

Comment: @tdelaney `requests` should send automatically content type when you specify `json=` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Unfortunatelly, when I try to set "json=data" it returns an error: `{"success":false,"status":400,"message":"An unknown error accured. Your unique error code: undefined"}`

Comment: And when I remove content-type it returns this: `{"success":false,"message":"to_number is missing..!"}`

Comment: Wait ! I removed the apostrophes on the data definition and it worked using your method. Figured it made more sense to define a json like a list instead of a string. Thank you !